# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I like to populate records according to created date from database using `CoreData` ,so I am using `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` for good feature ,as I add like:

```
@interface FBCDMasterViewController : UITableViewController 
                                        <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

Its giving error:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'

plase help out

Comment: Did you add the CoreData framework to your project?

Comment: yes ,i already using core data for other entities ,now i created one more entity where i required this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using coreData, simply adding the framework is not enough.
You also have to import the header in the files which need it.

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

This placed in your prefix Header file should fix it.

Comment: I'm happy that I could be of help :)